# making a toggle button to change panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have two panels at the top of my application and one button at the button. By default only panel one must be visible, but by clicking on the button panel one fades away, and panel two fades in. I created the layout, but I do not know how to achieve it.

```js
$(".panel2").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".grid-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".grid").toggleClass("open close");
    });
});
```

```css
div.app {
    margin:50px auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius:10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
div.app > .blur {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://goo.gl/0VTd9W);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
div.mainSection, div.dashboard{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}
div.mainSection{
  width:100%;
  height:85%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
}
div.dashboard{
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  bottom:0;
}
div.mainSection > .panel1,
div.mainSection > .panel2 {
    width: 100%;
    Height: 100%;
    Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.grid-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid:after, .grid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.grid.open {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.grid.open:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.grid.open:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.grid.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.grid.close:after, .grid.close:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.grid.close:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.grid.close:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
  <div class="blur"></div>
  <div class="mainSection">
    <div class="panel1">Panel1</div>
    <div class="panel2">Panel2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="dashboard">
    <div class="grid-button">
      <span class="grid open"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

First of all since I did `$('.panel2').hide();`, in page load first it loads the panel then hides it. How can I make it invisible from the beginning?

Secondly how can I make the panel2 visible only by pressing the button?

And finally is there anyway to add some transitions effects for changing panels?

Comment: Please clarify what you exactly want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
$(".grid-button").on("click", function() {
   var visibleObj = $('.mainSection div:visible');
   var inVisibleObj = $('.mainSection div:hidden');
   visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
       inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
   });
});
```

While for the visibility you need:

```
<div class="panel2" style="display: none;">Panel2</div>
```

The running snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".grid-button").on("click", function() {
    var visibleObj = $('.mainSection div:visible');
    var inVisibleObj = $('.mainSection div:hidden');
    visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
      inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div.app {
  margin:50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.app > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/0VTd9W);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
div.mainSection, div.dashboard{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}
div.mainSection{
  width:100%;
  height:85%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
}
div.dashboard{
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  bottom:0;
}
div.mainSection > .panel1,
div.mainSection > .panel2 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.grid-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid:after, .grid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.grid.open {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.grid.open:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.grid.open:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.grid.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.grid.close:after, .grid.close:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.grid.close:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.grid.close:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="app">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="mainSection">
        <div class="panel1">Panel1</div>
        <div class="panel2" style="display: none;">Panel2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="grid-button">
            <span class="grid open"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.

Answer (score 1):

To make one of the panels hidden in the first place, I'd use a `css` class called `hidden`:

```
.hidden{
  display : none;
}
```

Which simply makes what it sounds like, hiding the element.
Than, I'd set this class in the `HTML` decleration:

```
<div class="panel2 hidden">Panel2</div>
```

That will hide panel2 on page load, and by that you don't have to hide it using js code.

Than, I'd use a helper `css` class called `panel` that stands to be a panel identifier (you can either use the `data` attribute, or any other way of identifying those elements).
For 5 panels, it would look like this:

```
<div class="panel panel1">Panel1</div>
<div class="panel panel2 hidden">Panel2</div>
<div class="panel panel3 hidden">Panel3</div>
<div class="panel panel4 hidden">Panel4</div>
<div class="panel panel5 hidden">Pane5</div>
```

At last, to make this work for any number of panels you want (not necesseraly 2), I'd use a "carousel" effect to toggle the panels visibility, while having a way to keep track with them (adding and removing the `hidden` class), and use the fadeIn/fadeOut effect. (again, instead of identifying the panels using the `panel1,panel2,panel3...` classes, you can always use the `data` attribute (please read more about it in jQuery docs), or in any other way).

```
var currentPanel = 1;
$(".grid-button").on("click", function() {

    $(".grid").toggleClass("open close");        
    $(".panel"+currentPanel).fadeOut("normal", function(){
        $(this).addClass('hidden');
    });

    currentPanel = currentPanel >= $(".panel").length ?  1 :  currentPanel+1;
    $(".panel"+currentPanel).fadeIn().removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Just note that the `hidden` class actually "looses" it's functionality after the first click, since jQuery changes the `display` property inline, but I think that it might not be harmful to keep them anyway (it will be easier to track them).

You can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/j79y5kdb/3/

Comment: Thanks for your post. +1 for your pro solution.